# Sum up multiple rasters having the same name

Tags: python, gdal, r

How can I sum up the values of multiple rasters having the same name
e.g if I have 10 rasters named r1, r2 ...til r10 and I have an other 10 rasters having the same names r1, r2...till r10.

What I would like to do is to produce new 10 rasters r1' = r1 + r1, r2' = r2 + r2 ... r10' = r10 + r10.

Comment: Are these rasters files or R objects? How you got two R objects with the same name? Or are these two files in different locations? We need some more information to be able to help you since this isn't clear enough.